# Positivity of sequences

Tags: enumerative-combinatorics, generating-functions, characters, hankel-matrices, total-positivity

Totally positive sequences $\lbrace a_n\rbrace_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ are defined as those such that the Töplitz matrix $A_{ij}=a_{i-j}$ is totally positive (all its minors are non-negative). An interesting result by Aissen et al. (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1063359/?page=1) states that the generating function $\sum_n a_n x^n$ for a totally positive sequence can be expressed as the product of functions $e^{\gamma x}$, $1+\alpha x$ and $\frac{1}{1-\beta x}$, for $\alpha\geq 0,\beta\geq 0, \gamma \geq 0$.

A different but related concept is Hankel positive sequences, where the definition is the same as the previous one for the Töplitz case but over the Hankel matrix $B_{ij}=a_{i+j}$. Now I am looking for an analogue of the Aissen et al. result but for the generating functions of Hankel positive sequences.

Moreover, I am interested in the *Hankel$\pm$Töplitz* cases, where I declare a sequence Hankel$\pm$Töplitz positive when the minors of $B_{ij}\pm A_{ij}$ are all non-negative.

Aissen et at. results are quite old so I wonder if maybe this things were already found somewhere. Have you heard about something similar? Or any intuition of how to find these generalizations?

Comment: This might be useful: [Hamburger moment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburger_moment_problem)

Comment: Indeed! actually it is a classic result (Stieltjes, Gantmakher-Krein) that a sequence is Hankel positive iff $a_n=\int x^n d\mu(x)$ in the interval $[0,\infty)$, so not exactly Hamburger's but almost :)

Comment: the link you give does not work; is it https://www.pnas.org/content/37/5/303 ?

Comment: if you have access to mathschinet (https://mathscinet.ams.org/), you can look up 33 references to this paper, with reviews.

Comment: you can also use (free!) zbmath: https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0042.29205 lists 34 citations of this paper (https://zbmath.org/?q=rf%3A3065150)